# Break Program whilst in a while true - try and except

Tags: python

I need my program to break if the user inputs 'no'. At the moment, the program will not break, and when 'no' is inputed, the try and except restarts

```
while final_answer_check == True:

try:
    final_answer = str(input("Do you want a copy of the answers?"))
    if final_answer.lower() == "no":
        final_answer_check = False
```

I'd expect the program to break, but it just asks "Do you want a copy of the answers?" again

Comment: input is already in a str

Comment: where is your except block?

Comment: Oh and where is the loop?

Comment: DirtyBit - I have removed the except and loop parts so that it will fit into the question panel. thanks for the help

Comment: you should always post a code snippet that could reproduce the problem you are facing, see if the answer I posted helps?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comments, this should do:

```
final_answer_check = True   # a boolean flag 

while final_answer_check:    # while the flag is set to true
    try:
        final_answer = str(input("Do you want a copy of the answers?"))
        if final_answer.lower() == "no":
            final_answer_check = False
    except:
        pass
```

**EDIT**:

A better approach however could be to use a infinite loop with a `break`:

```
while True:
    try:
        final_answer = input("Do you want a copy of the answers?")
        if final_answer.lower() == "no":
            break
    except:
        pass
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Do you want a copy of the answers?no

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define the variable `final_answer_check` and set the value into `True`. If you build your code in a block of `try...except`, you need to make it complete, not only `try`.

```
final_answer_check = True
while final_answer_check == True:
    try:
        final_answer = str(input("Do you want a copy of the answers?"))
        if final_answer.lower() == "no":
            final_answer_check = False
        else:
            final_answer_check = True
    except:
        print ("your another code should be here")
```